# Photoelectrochemical (PEC) water splitting

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, photochemistry, catalysis

I'm starting to prepare for my research project on photoelectrochemical (PEC) splitting of water into H and O using (F doped) titanium dioxide as the photoanode. I've been unsuccessfully searching in the literature for any particular reason(s) which could make PEC better than other methods of photocatalytic water splitting. What is, if anything, special about PEC water splitting compared to other approaches?

Comment: Splitting of water is an electrochemical reaction. Any photocatalytic process is by definition photoelectrochemical.  You need to clarify what you mean by the two different terms.